# How to put this box to start at the top of the page?

Tags: html, css

I have created a box in html with css code but it does not starts at the top of the screen. There's a little gap. I will show you.

[image]

Comment: Remove the default margin on the body element

Comment: How to do that? This is my code:

Comment: .box {
            width: 1890px;
            height: 100px;
   border: 0px solid #ccc;
   color: black;
   background-color: #23282A;

Comment: Cool. Duplicate answer. I have found it! Thank you!